# Text Keyboard with Numbers Mode

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have an EditText which accepts numbers and characters as input. Most of the time the user enters numbers and I want to have the text keyboard but it should be in symbols or numbers mode where you can enter the numbers directly. Is this possible?

On the Nexus S there are characters on the keyboard with input type set as "number" but I cannot add characters.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you mean you want it to default to numeric but make characters possible.. This is not doable

Comment: That was my first try. I want the text keyboard and switch it to the numbers mode. There should be a button to do this.

Comment: you can do it by implementig your custom keyboard. But it is much more chalanging than set one flag.

Comment: @SherifelKhatib I had to do a lot of research on this for an app and found that it is possible, however the keyboard implementation needs to support it (not all do).

Comment: @jprofitt it would be nice if you add it as an answer. sharing knowledge...

Comment: @SherifelKhatib Unfortunately I just recall my findings, but not the actual implementation specifics.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it works but works at least on my Motorola RAZR

editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

This show numeric keyboard but if you need you can switch to the text mode

Comment: Worked on my Samsung 7.7 Tab 2 but not my Pantech.  I believe this technique is keyboard implementation specific.